# Networking in MVVM

Tags: swift, mvvm

I have an app with MVVM and I don't know where implement networking calls. In ViewModel, in Controller? Another pattern to implement networking?

I think ViewModel is the best place but I'm not totally sure

Comment: You can consider implementing your networking calls with the command-query responsibility separation pattern, place them in a service (facade pattern) and init them in your controller.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that pattern, I'm going to look for more information about that

Comment: To best of my knowledge, MVVM is a architecture to organize the business logic and the UI parts. And a networking service doesn't care about both of these two parts. So you should write an independent networking service outside the entire MVVM, which technically means networking service can compile without the MVVM code, and then consume its service at some proper point within your MVVM, which is typically controller.

Comment: @NandiinBao can the network service be consumed in viewmodel and not in the controller? Eg. in viewmodel i have a function that makes a call to the network service layer. Then in the controller, I call this function when needed. And after getting the results from the network call, the view model notifies the viewcontroller, after which the viewcontroller updates the ui.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
// Your network calls
class NetworkQuery {

}

class NetworkCommand {

}

// Service (Facade pattern)
class NetworkServices {

    let networkQuery: NetworkQuery!
    let networkCommand: NetworkCommand!
}

// Your controller or view model, you can place them in either both
class MyControllerOrViewModel {

    let networkServices: NetworkServices!
}
```

Just now two cents' worth..

Answer (score 1):

this is how I implement services/network calls in my viewModel using MVVM and Combine:

the view model:

```
protocol myViewModeling {
   var yourData: [YourData] { get set } 
   func getData() 
}

final class myViewModel: myViewModeling & ObservableObject {

   // MARK: - Properties
   private let service: myServicing // your service protocol 

   // MARK: - Published Properties
   @Published var yourData: [YourData] = .init()

   // MARK: - Initializer
   init(service: myServicing = MyService()) {
      self.service = service
   }

   func getData() {
      Task { [weak self] in
         guard let self = self else { return }
         let result = await self.service.getData()
           switch result {
              case let .success(response):
                await MainActor.run {
                  self.yourData = response.data
                }
               case let .failure(error):
                print(error.customMessage)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then myService:

```
protocol MyServicing {
    typealias CustomResult = Result<YourResponse, YourError>
    func getData() async -> CustomResult // I use async await but you can use Future, Completions etc 
}

class MyServuce, MyServicing {
   func getData() async -> CustomResult  {
      await // your request 
   }
}
```

then in inject the view model in the view (swiftui or uikit) and from there I just call `viewModel.getData()`.

Using protocols for your service makes super easy unit testing as you pass to your view model a `MockService` which implements `MyServicing`

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways you can perform networking calls in SwiftUI. You don't really need to use View Models. In SwiftUI, views are view models.

**OPTION 1**

If your view is just consuming the API and want to display the result then you can use the following approach.

```
// Stateless StoreHTTPClient 
struct StoreHTTPClient {
    
    func getProducts() async throws -> [Product] {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: URL(string: "https://api.escuelajs.co/api/v1/products")!)
        return try JSONDecoder().decode([Product].self, from: data)
    }
    
}

// Product model 
struct Product: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
}

// ContentView 
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let storeHTTPClient = StoreHTTPClient()
    @State private var products: [Product] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(products) { product in
            Text(product.title)
        }.task {
            do {
                products = try await storeHTTPClient.getProducts()
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nice and simple!

**OPTION 2:**

If you want a single place which acts as a single source of truth then you can create a StoreModel and that can hold the entire state of the application. For more complicated apps you can divide the app models based on their bounded context. Keep in mind StoreModel is NOT a View Model. We don't need a separate StoreModel for each screen.

```
// StoreModel is NOT a ViewModel. It does not perform formatting and unlike a VM you don't need a StoreModel for each screen of your app. For small sized apps, a single StoreModel should be enough.
@MainActor
class StoreModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let storeHTTPClient: StoreHTTPClient
    @Published var products: [Product] = []
    
    init(storeHTTPClient: StoreHTTPClient) {
        self.storeHTTPClient = storeHTTPClient
    }
    
    func populateProducts() async throws {
        products = try await storeHTTPClient.getProducts()
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject private var storeModel: StoreModel
    @State private var products: [Product] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List(products) { product in
            Text(product.title)
        }.task {
            do {
                try await storeModel.populateProducts()
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(StoreModel(storeHTTPClient: StoreHTTPClient()))
    }
}
```